# What is site-packages\pkg_resources & Why is it Saying I Have Dependancy Problems?

Tags: python, debugging, command-line, import, package

## Question:

How do I understand the output of
    `raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)`
to resolve dependencies & why aren't these conflics being discovered when I install via `pip`?

This is what gets spit out when that `VersionConflict().with_context()` gets executed:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: 
(
    foo-module <some HIGHER version number> (c:\<blahblah>\lib\site-packages),
    Requirement.parse('foo-module[autorest]==<some LOWER version number>'),
    set([<some fat list of modules>])
)
```

## Some Background:

I wrote a tool to quickly turn on/off & check the status of some of my Azure-VMs. I have the `azure`, `msrest`, & `msrestazure` packages as dependencies. I thought I got the `requirements.txt` right, but clearly that's not the case.

You can find my broken piece-o'-garbagio right [here](https://github.com/rtruxal/azure_utils).

This particular dependency-conflict-discovery issue **happens at runtime,** & seems to effect python cli programs.

#### Specifically, it appears to effect packages installed locally (via something like `pip install .`,) & which use a `setup.py` file containing an `entry_points=` argument like the one below:

```
setup(...
    entry_points={'console_script = foo_package.__barModule__:baz_function'},
...)
```

(a search for `pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict` turns up a lot of questions around `scrapy`.)

## My Issue:

I don't know where to **start** looking for version-info to resolve this conflict. Here's the traceback I get when I run `$ azureutils turnon vm1`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\Scripts\azureutils-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3138, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3122, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3151, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 666, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 679, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "C:\Users\NUNYA-BITNASS\Anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 872, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (azure-common 1.1.8 (c:\users\NUNYA-BITNASS\anaconda2\envs\azurerm2.7\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('azure-common[autorest]==1.1.4'), set(['azure-mgmt-batch', 'azure-mgmt-redis', 'azure-mgmt-powerbiembedded', 'azure-mgmt-notificationhubs', 'azure-mgmt-scheduler', 'azure-mgmt-network', 'azure-mgmt-storage', 'azure-graphrbac', 'azure-mgmt-cognitiveservices', 'azure-mgmt-keyvault', 'azure-batch', 'azure-mgmt-compute', 'azure-mgmt-authorization', 'azure-mgmt-logic', 'azure-mgmt-web', 'azure-mgmt-commerce', 'azure-mgmt-cdn', 'azure-mgmt-resource']))
```

Now, I'm no stranger to terrible tracebacks which make their way through 50 modules I didn't write & don't understand. I usually look at the end, and this is how I'm reading that last line:

```
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (azure-common 1.1.<higher digit> (c:\<blahblah>\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('azure-common[autorest]==1.1.<lower digit>'), set([<some fat list of modules>]))
```

## Bringing it back around:

...soooo yeah! Not quite sure where to start untangling this one. Any help understanding what's happening with `site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py` would be amazing.